# Alternatives to window.onload

Tags: javascript, html, onload

Is there a different option than `window.onload=function;` or `<body onload="function();">` to call a function after the page loads.

I have a script found on the net satisfies my needs, but it overrides `window.onload`,  so this prevents me from using the native `window.onload`.

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 9):

Use addEventListener instead. Unfortunately it does not work in IE, but you can work around that by also implementing attachEvent.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (){
    alert('Function #1');
});

window.attachEvent('onload', function (){
    alert('Function #1');
});
```

Comment: this is the preferred way to do things when not using frameworks. Also, since IE usage is declining, attachEvent is also decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easy, grab [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) and use the document.ready function to execute the logic you want to run in window.onload.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but when I remove brackets, the function works.

Replace

```
window.onload = loadPage();
```

with

```
window.onload = loadPage;
function loadPage() {
if (document.getElementById("testElement").value)
    alert('whew');
}
```

and it works.

Comment: This is because the first example tells the page that its onload function is the return type of loadPage() - and unless this is returning a function, it won't be of much use. The second example, which works gives it a reference to the function, rather than invoking it (using brackets), so you tell it that onload is a function.

Comment: Not really what they are asking for here

Answer (score 1):

Not an alternative, but a workaround, yes.

If your found-on-the-net script (FOTN) creates the `onload`, simply create your own `onload` afterwards, like so:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){ console.log("FOTN"); }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = window.onload;
window.onload = function(){ 
    console.log("Handling before FOTN"); 
    a(); 
    console.log("Handling after FOTN"); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The prerequirement is that your `onload` is defined at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This executes `function()` straight away and assigns the function's return value to `window.onload`. This is usually not what you want. `function()` would have to return a function for this to make sense.

Answer (score -2):

You can have multiple onLoad functions, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: No, you can't have multiple window.onload triggered.