# CanvasJs chart not rendering

Tags: javascript, charts, html5-canvas

My chart is not rendering. When I load the page, it only shows white background. I don't know how to debug this. Can anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 500px; width: 50%;"></div>
</body>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js">


          var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
              data: [
                  {
                      type: "column",
                      dataPoints: [
                          { x: 10, y: 10 },
                          { x: 20, y: 15 },
                          { x: 30, y: 25 },
                          { x: 40, y: 30 },
                          { x: 50, y: 28 }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          });

          chart.render();

  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Move your scripts into `<body>` just before `</body>` tag.

Comment: yes you are correct, ive realized it and now i made it but it is not rendering now

Answer (score 1):

You need to write proper HTML code and add `window.onload` handler to run your code just after page loading:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 500px; width: 50%;"></div>
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        window.onload = function () {

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            data: [
                {
                    type: "column",
                    dataPoints: [
                        { x: 10, y: 10 },
                        { x: 20, y: 15 },
                        { x: 30, y: 25 },
                        { x: 40, y: 30 },
                        { x: 50, y: 28 }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        chart.render();

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPD.** Example without `window.onload` (don't forget import `canvasjs` before your actual code):

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  data: [
    {
      type: "column",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 10 },
        { x: 20, y: 15 },
        { x: 30, y: 25 },
        { x: 40, y: 30 },
        { x: 50, y: 28 }
      ]
    }
  ]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 500px; width: 50%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: idk why window.onload is not working from me, tried running alert("test") inside that window.onload but when i load the page again no one is alerting.. but when i remove the onload it gives me "ReferenceError: CanvasJS is not defined"

Comment: @Poorprogrammer you can try some alternative methods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686083/alternatives-to-window-onload

Answer (score 0):

try this hope this will work

```
<html>
<head>  
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
              data: [
                  {
                      type: "column",
                      dataPoints: [
                          { x: 10, y: 10 },
                          { x: 20, y: 15 },
                          { x: 30, y: 25 },
                          { x: 40, y: 30 },
                          { x: 50, y: 28 }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          });
          chart.render();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

result
[image]

Comment: it gives me "CanvasJS.Chart is not defined"

Comment: @MuhammadFazeel your js code run before `canvasjs` imports.

Comment: how are u running ur html file>>

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJ2QVQCE8P9I check it out here it is working fine i think u have issue while running ur html file ...

Comment: u have to run it on server or local host server this will solve ur issue